# Binding with ElementName not working on a DataTemplate on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0

Why a binding with `ElementName` on a `DataTemplate` of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` does not work (will always fallback to a default value or `FallbackValue`) under Windows XP with .Net 4.0?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="AAA" Width="62">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=IsEnabled}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But Windows 7 and later this binding works as expected.

The only way to make it work under Windows XP, is by using [x:Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: tough question... would be interesting why this is failing. Anyway XP support has endend. I would not bother too much about dinosaurs https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/end-of-xp-support

Comment: Yeah, XP is dead. But it's way tough to tell my boss and his clients. Sad life. :/

Answer (score 1):

WPF does not support Windows XP.

You can tell your boss by following this source: [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx). It's from Microsoft and this is official.